# Invalid AssemblyVersion

Tags: c#, version

I'm using *Automatically increment revision with each publish* in my application deployment

[image: Publish version screen shot]

In combination with `AssemblyInfo.cs`:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion( "2.0.0.*" )]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion( "2.0.0.0" )]
```

And I want to show user current version of software by using:

```
protected void InitializeVersionInfo()
{
    Assembly a = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    Version v = System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed
            ? System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion
            : Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;

    string version = String.Format( System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
        @"Tool - Version {0}.{1}.{2} (r{3})", v.Major, v.Minor, v.Build, v.Revision );
    VersionLabel.Text = version;
}
```

But I'm getting different version numbers:

[image: Debugger screenshot]

What am I doing wrong or what I am missing?

How can I get software to display `2.0.0.12`?

Comment: If you want specific version then why're you using `Automatically increment revision` at all?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I was expecting the `Revesion` and `v.Revision` to have the same number, I don't care whether it's `+1` (incremented by one) or `+log(rand())*137`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version specified on publish tab is a "Package Version". This version string will be embedded in package manifest file.

Version specified in AssemblyInfo.cs is an assembly version. This version is embedded into assembly at compile time, before assembly is packaged. "*" enables version auto-increment on each build (even is build will be never published). This version is unrelated to package version.

If you need package version to match assembly version then you have to manually sync them (i.e. put specific, non-wildcard version to both Publish settings and AssemblyInfo.cs before publishing).

Also, you can just display Package Version instead on Assembly Version:

```
if (System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
{
    VersionLabel.Text = System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using `Automatically increment revision` feature.

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion( "2.0.0.*" )]
```

Note * is incremented each time you build your application randomly.

If you need specific version don't use *Automatically increment feature*. ie update it manually like

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion( "2.0.0.12" )]
```

Don't forget to turn off the *Automatically increment feature*